# Return type of const int &

Tags: c++

```
const int z1 = 5;
const int & giveMeNumber1(){
    return z1;
}

int z2 = 6;
const int & giveMeNumber2(){
    return z2;
}

int main(){
    int y = giveMeNumber1();
}
```

1. The return type of both functions appear to be `const int`. Am I correct? If so then why am I able to assign `int y = giveMeNumber1();`?
2. Why do these functions do not return the actual addresses of `z1` and `z2` respectively. When I write:

   ```
   int x = 3; cout << &x << endl;
   ```

   The address of the `x` variable is printed, so:

   ```
   cout << giveMeNumber1() << endl;
   ```

   Should print the address as well (`const int & return type`), but it prints `5`.

Comment: Part of the confusion is probably from the fact that an `int const&` (or `const int&`, there's no difference) is a pretty useless thing anyway and can almost always be safely replaced by a simple `int`. Constant references are relevant for "big" data types such as `std::string` or `std::vector`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> 1. The return type of both functions appear to be const int. Am I
>    correct? If so then why am I able to assign int y = giveMeNumber1();?

No, you're not correct. The return type of these functions is `const int &`. Note the ampersand **&** at the end. It's a **const-reference to an int**.

`giveMeNumber1()` returns a `const int &` which references an integer left value (that is `z1`). You cannot modify the referenced object through the const-reference (which is the meaning behind `const` here). But you can copy the value. So what happens is that the referenced value is copied to `y`.

> 2. Why do these functions do not return the actual addresses of z1 and z2 respectively.
>
> When I write:
>
> `int x = 3; cout << &x << endl;`
>
> The address of the x variable is printed, so:
>
> `cout << giveMeNumber1() << endl;`
>
> Should print the address as well (`const int & return type`), but it prints 5.

Again, these functions return a **const-reference to an int**. They don't return the address.

---

It seems that you're getting confused over the use of `&` for pointers/addresses and references.

Pointers store an address to another memory location. So you can say that they "point to an object".

References are somewhat like pointers but they act like the object itself. You can only initialize them with a left-value, you can't initialize a reference with a literal value like `int& ref = 1`.

Anything you can do with the original object you can do with a reference. But you cannot reassign a reference, once it references one object you cannot change that, although there are [standard wrappers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) that can be used to overcome this.

Using a reference just like the object itself includes getting its address. Since your function returns a reference, you can also get the address of the referenced object. You could've written your `cout` line like this,

```
cout << &giveMeNumber1() << endl;  // The & here gets the address of the left value
// returned by the function.
```

If you wanted to return the address of the variable then you could've written your function like,

```
// The returned type is a "pointer to const int", note the *
const int* giveMeNumber1() {
    return &z1;
}
```

However, don't refer to a function's return value as "returning its address", rather "returning a pointer". This way your original cout line would directly print the address,

```
cout << giveMeNumber1() << endl;
```

And if you wanted to refer to the pointed value, you would write,

```
cout << *giveMeNumber1() << endl;
```

Here's a short, denser, example to help you distinguish references from pointers,

```
int  x = 16;
int* p = &x; // Pointer p initialized with the address of x
int& r =  x; // r is a reference to x

const int& cr = x; // const reference to x

std::cout <<  x << std::endl; // x's value = 16
std::cout << &x << std::endl; // x's address

std::cout <<  p << std::endl; // p's value = address of x
std::cout << *p << std::endl; // int value that's in the address pointed to by p == x == 16
std::cout << &p << std::endl; // p´s address (p is a variable as well)

std::cout <<  r << std::endl; // x's value = 16
std::cout << &r << std::endl; // x's address (you can't get the address of the reference itself)

r  = 2;  // r is a reference of x, so now x = 2
cr = 2; // This won't do, you can't assign to a const reference

int y = r;  // Ok, copying the value in x, 2, to y
int z = cr; // Ok, copying 2 to z
```

EDIT: Edited to properly address the OP's question(s).

Comment: I don't see how this really answers the question, despite the big green tick. You've just regurgitating a very short book description of pointer & reference syntax, without doing much to address the more fundamental misunderstandings shown in the question. Also, it wouldn't kill you to left-align your asterisks and ampersands when writing out types, as _that_ is what will make the difference clear.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I don't know either why my answer was accepted. Don't blame me. And I actually wrote the "code" myself. I fixed the indentation and you already addressed these issues you mentioned in your answer. I have nothing to add there.

Comment: I'm not "blaming" anyone I'm just offering my critique, as I would on any answer on any question. Unfortunately you misread/misunderstood my suggestion regarding alignment.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I hope I got the alignment right this time. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: They do return the address, but a reference is syntactic sugar to the compiler, it doesn't show you the address unless you use `&`.

Comment: They do _not_ "return the address". Ben you know better than to propagate harmful, decades-old misconceptions about reference semantics and the abstraction that is C++!

Comment: @BenVoigt Technically they do yes, much like pointers. But as the user you don't need to know that, so I guess it's better to assume the functions don't "return the address".

Answer (score 5):

Wow, the misconceptions. Okay, let's see what we can do about that.

> The return type of both functions appear to be `const int`. Am I correct?

No. The return type of both functions is `const int&`. Reference to `const` `int`.

> If so then why am I able to assign `int y = giveMeNumber1();` ?

Because you're copying into `y`? You can copy a `const` object into a non-`const` object just fine. A `const` thing cannot be modified, but copying something doesn't modify it.

> Why do these functions do not return the actual addresses of `z1` and `z2` respectively.

Because they're not supposed to. They return references to `z1` and `z2`.

> ```
> cout << giveMeNumber1() << endl;
> ```
>
> should print the address as well (`const int &` return type)

Complete nonsense. Which C++ book are you using? A return type of `const int&` (at least you got it right this time) denotes a *reference*. A reference is not a pointer, or an "address". I don't know where you got the notion that `cout << giveMeNumber1()` would print any address but … it won't.

For further information, re-read [your C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/560648)… this time, *cover to cover*!

Comment: They DO return the addresses, which you can determine by printing the address of the expression.  The confusion comes from thinking that using `cout`'s `operator<<` on a reference will print the address, which is completely erroneous.

Comment: @BenVoigt: No, references are not addresses. The functions return references, not addresses. That the address of the referent is the same as the address of the, er, referent, is irrelevant.

Comment: Returning a reference transfers the address information to the caller.  The "return value" is not an address, but the address is returned.

Comment: @BenVoigt: You could say that about literally every single value returned from a function. That makes it a vacuous statement and, in this particular instance, a dangerously misleading one. If nothing else, there is a good bloomin' reason that C++ abstracts away implementation details so why are we dropping it now, right when it's most harmful to do so? There are enough misconceptions about references vs pointers going around already, certainly so in this question! :(

Comment: No, when a primitive is returned by value, there's no address information transferred during the return process.  The reason that `cout << reference` doesn't print an address is not because there's no address to print, as you claim, but because the semantics of `operator<<` with a parameter of type `const int&` are to print the value of the parameter and not its address.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Sure there is. If there weren't, it would be impossible for the CPU to copy the value's constituent bytes from the object found in the return expression to the result object in the calling scope.

Comment: You're the one making statements that are not true in all implementations.  Most implementations place a return value of primitive type in `EAX` (x86), `RAX` (x86_64), `r1` (ARM) and these don't even have addresses, ergo no address is transferred during the return process.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I'm a little confused as to what your goal is in this comment thread. Perhaps I'm missing something, but your input so far appears to be starting arguments based on levels of abstraction that you've chosen entirely arbitrarily, that are not the level of abstraction deliberately "implemented" by the C++ standard, and that harmfully confuse newcomers as to what references _are_ and _aren't_. I'm trying to work out why you would do that.

Comment: I am confused. The return type of function `giveMeNumber1()` is a const reference to int, so it is returing a reference to z1, but you keep saying it is making a copy of z1.

Comment: @NitinAggarwal: `giveMeNumber1()` returns a reference to int, but then you're copy-initialising `y` with that int value. It's `int y = giveMeNumber1();`, not `const int& y = giveMeNumber1();`.

Answer (score -4):

for returning z1 as a reference

```
return &z1;
```

In reality you are returning the address that is represented by the value contained in the variable z1. Not the address of z1 in memory.

that value will tuck nicely into an int.

Comment: `&z1;` yields a pointer, and that pointer cannot be returned as an `int const&`. What happens "in reality" is a compiler-implementation detail and has nothing to do with C++ language semantics. Finally, if you do `&z1`, then you do get the address of the `z1` variable, regardless of what value is contained in the variable.

Comment: apparently it can physically be done cause I've done it before and he's doing it now.   but with incorrect result.

Comment: This suggestion has nothing to do with references. Also, your description of a pointer is wrong. Oh, and assuming that all pointers fit inside `int`s is wrong too.